# Xamarin.IOS standard animations lagging UI

Tags: ios, .net, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am having trouble with the standard animations and transitions on a Xamarin native IOS app. Animations and transitions are locking all other UI elements and causing them to remain non reactive to touch for until 1-1.5s later.

This happen in the following cases

- Soft keyboard: Whenever a soft keyboard is invoked from an input box, after closing the soft keyboard, all other UI elements in the view remain non reactive to touch for a noticeable small time
- Navigation transitions: Whenever I navigate back from one view to the next one (using the navigation bar standard chevron), the elements in the previous view remain inactive for a bit
- Closing modal views: Whenever I close a modal view, the rest of the UI stays non-reactive for a noticeable small time

This seems to be caused by the UI waiting for the animation to finish completely. Even when the animation seems to have finished (visually) the UI seems to be waiting for it to finish completely before becoming reactive again. The effect is quite noticeable and gives the user the impression that the app is not responding.

Is there a way to configure this behavior in Xamarin native? Perhaps a way to speed up the animations or a way to indicate that the UI should be reactive even if the animation has not finished?

Comment: Make sure your UI changes are made on the main thread, and you could show a piece of code that has this issue

Comment: Can you please make sure that no one is responding to any of those events? The WillAppear Controller method when you navigate back for instance

Comment: Also does this issue only happen on the simulator or does it happen on the physical devices as well